# Removing a DropDown List from a layout

Tags: android, xml

Hi i need to add a extra dropdown to my layout so i'm trying to remove all the dropdowns and add again with the extra dropdown.

```
    public void dropDown(int foodItems){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foods);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    RelativeLayout mRlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.add);

    for (int i = 1; i <= foodItems; i++) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mRparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
        spin.setId(i);
        mRparams.setMargins(0, 190 * i, 0, 0);
        spin.setLayoutParams(mRparams);
        mRlayout.addView(spin);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

}
```

When i run the `dropDown` method with the new count it overwrite the layout without replacing

[image]

first i had 3 dropdowns then with the new `foodItems` of 4 it overwrite

my `add` RelativeLayout

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/add"
        style="@style/linearParent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/loginViewsMargin">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing all view first `mRlayout.removeAllViews();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `remove` views from your `RelativeLayout` and then add again to escape overlap

```
mRlayout.removeAllViews();
for (int i = 1; i <= foodItems; i++) {
    ....
}
```